# jquery ajax call fails on facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, web-applications

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postolayi(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'yorum_gonder.php',
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(cevap){
                $("#sonuc").html(cevap)
            }
        })
    }
</script>
<form id="form1">
    <label for="textfield">Name</label>
    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="ad" />
    <input onclick="postolayi();" type="button" />
</form>
```

Why this code is not working on facebook apps? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Must be over a ssl / https, try change the jquery-link:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js